# Obtaining Channel State Information (CSI) from WiFi AP's on mobile devices

Tags: android, indoor-positioning-system, google-indoor-maps

From an app development context point of view, is it possible to obtain Channel State Information (CSI) information from a WiFi access point from this smart device's WiFi card? I would like to use this information to create a CSI - fingerprinting system for an indoor localization project at my University. CSI information may be better than just RSSI values.

From what I currently know referencing a research paper regarding indoor localization, CSI information is somehow accessible to any mobile device that supports the 802.11n (and most likely more recent) protocols. The testing will be conducted on either a Nexus 7 tablet or an LG G3 smart phone. I was unable to find technical documentation that listed out the specifics of their WiFi cards.

If there is a more appropriate place to post this question, please let me know.

Thanks,

jgolen

Answer (score 3):

There is a recent project called "nexmon" which extracts CSI information from Nexus 5 smartphone. This is the link to the project: https://github.com/seemoo-lab/mobisys2018_nexmon_channel_state_information_extractor

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get CSI from the beamforming training signal by firing a null data frame, and the device should reply - it's a three frame transaction - lookup beamforming in the standard. According to the standard, any device post (802.11n) should do it. It seems a lot of phone makers (all probably) are not enabling this, or keeping it to themselves, because it's very useful, hence the wifi localization option on your phone.